# .Ajax with jQuery and MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

Im trying to create an ajax (post) event that will populate a table in a div on button click.

I have a list of groups, when you click on a group, I would like the table to "disappear" and the members that belong to that group to "appear".

My problem comes up when using jQuery's .ajax...

When I click on the button, it is looking for a controller that doesnt exist, and a controller that is NOT referenced. I am, however, using AREAS (MVC2), and the area is named Member_Select where the controller is named MemberSelect. When I click on the button, I get a 404 stating it cannot find the controller Member_Select. I have examined the link button and it is set to Member_Select when clicked on, but here's the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/MemberSelect/GetMembersFromGroup',
    success: function(html) { $("#groupResults").html(html); }
});
```

I havent been able to find any examples/help online.
Any thoughts/suggestions/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your route definitions?

Comment: Is '/MemberSelect/GetMembersFromGroup' the URL you'd expect (remember that this tells the browser to go to the root of your site) - you state in another comment that you could create a link in the navigation dynamically - is the nav link the same as that? Or is it '/Member_Select/MemberSelect/GetUsersFromGroup'? Have you got an AcceptVerbs attribute on your controller to only accept Get requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried navigating to /MemberSelect/GetMembersFromGroup to see what you get? - if it's 404'ing it's because the route can't be matched to a controller/ action.

I've not used the new areas functionality, but I'm not sure that the URL you've got is correct...I would have thought it would have been /AREANAME/MemberSelect/GetMembersFromGroup...but I could be wrong..!

Comment: yeah, I've tried starting with the area name and going all the way down the chain, I've tried creating the url "dynamically" with 
<%= Url.Action("Function", "MemberSelect", new { area = "Member_Select" }, null) %> (This is the same as the navigate link on my main menu, so I KNOW it gets to the correct page)

Comment: It seems to have to do with the way the link(s) were generated. Removing the href="..." from the <a> tag seemed to work. I guess it did have to do with the way MVC2 routes?

Answer (score 1):

When I did this, it worked fine. I didn't use POST and I don't know what AREAS means.

```
$("#item").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, responseFn) {
        addMessage("search on: '" + req.term + "'<br/>", true);

        $.ajax({
            url     : ajaxUrlBase1 + "GetMatchedCities/" + req.term,
            cache   : false,
            type    : "GET", // http method
            success : function(msg){
                // ajax call has returned
                var result = msg;
                var a = [];
                if (result !== null){
                  for(var i=0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    a.push({label: result[i].prop1, id: result[i].prop2});
                  }
                } 
                responseFn(a);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: AREAS are part of MVC2, they help organize your project (among other helpfulness!)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

area_name/controller_name/action_name

Instead of doing $.ajax I would use jQuery Form Plugin.
and have my form set as:

```
Html.BeginForm("Index","AdminArea/Admin",FormMethod.Post,
new { id="form-user", name="form-user"})
```

To use jQuery Form Plugin have a look here:

http://arturito.net/2010/12/02/asp-net-mvc2-jquery-form-post-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You cold save your url in a Hidden Form element in (Html.HiddenForm()) and use the #id javascript operator to retrieve it.  Just found this out today.